# Cassandra restore from a higher node cluster to a lower node cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I have 2 node cluster A with replication factor = 2. I tried taking backup of the above said cluster A and restored it to a single node cluster B. But after restoring when i went to Cluster B and checked for RF , it showed 2 like it was on cluster A.
Should cassandra automatically convert the rf to 1 while restoring to B? Why is it still 2 in that single node cluster B?
And will it be ok to be RF = 2 in single node B?

I am using sstableloader and cassandra version 3.10

Comment: What was the replication factor specified when you created keyspace in the cluster B?

Comment: I am trying to restore  data from A to B. So basically i dont want to create a keyspace on B right. It should automatically be created in that restore

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/toolsSStables/toolsBulkloader.html#toolsBulkloader__bulkloader-preparing-the-target-environment

Comment: it won't create it automatically, as documentation states: "Before loading the data, you must define the schema of the target tables with CQL.", and this will require that you adjust replication factor for keyspaces